# How to achieve a wave animation on canvas ? using delay or another technique

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am basically trying to make several balls in line together and get the balls move up and down on the Y axis but each ball starts with a bit of delay so that in the end it should create infinite wave effects

I first tried with increasing velocity and although it creates the effect I want but it does it temporarily in that it keeps increasing the dynamics of the animation.

I think only if i can make the each ball starts animating at a different time it will solve this issue. any suggestion to this ?

check out the animation on my codepen https://codepen.io/jinnn0/pen/zgRrKm?editors=0010

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight


function Circle(x, y, radius, color, velocity, amplitude) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.color = color
  this.radius = radius
  this.radian = 1
  this.velocity = velocity
  this.amplitude = amplitude
  this.acceleration = 0.001
  this.count = 0


  this.draw = function(){
    c.beginPath()
    c.fillStyle = color
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
    c.lineWidth = 3
    c.stroke()
    c.fill()
    c.closePath()
 }

 this.update = function(){
   this.draw()

   this.radian += this.velocity
   this.y = y + Math.sin(this.radian) * this.amplitude
   this.count ++
  }
}



let circleArr;
function init(){
 circleArr = []
 let radius = 25
 let x = radius
 let y = 200
 let color = "rgba(140, 140, 140)"
 let velocity = 0.05
 let amplitude = 100

 for( let i =0; i < 10; i++ ) {  
   circleArr.push(new Circle(x, y, radius, color, velocity, 
     amplitude))
   x += radius * 2

  // velocity += 0.001
  }
}


function animate(){
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

  for(let i = 0; i < circleArr.length; i++) {
    circleArr[i].update()   
  }

 requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}


init()
animate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the start timestamp using [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/now) then compare the ellapsed time since the start of the animation against a specified delay (in ms) for each ball (note that I've also changed the starting radian to 0 so that the balls don't "jump" to the bottom when the animation starts, and the start y so that we actually see the balls in the snippet preview):

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
const start = Date.now();
const delay = 2000;

function Circle(x, y, radius, color, velocity, amplitude, delay) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.color = color
  this.radius = radius
  this.radian = 0
  this.velocity = velocity
  this.amplitude = amplitude
  this.acceleration = 0.001
  this.count = 0
  this.delay = delay


  this.draw = function(){
    c.beginPath()
    c.fillStyle = color
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
    c.lineWidth = 3
    c.stroke()
    c.fill()
    c.closePath()
 }

 this.update = function(ellapsed){
   
   this.draw()
   if (ellapsed > this.delay) {
      this.radian += this.velocity
      this.y = y + Math.sin(this.radian) * this.amplitude
      this.count ++
   
   }
   
  }
}



let circleArr;
function init(){
 circleArr = []
 let radius = 25
 let x = radius
 let y = 130
 let color = "rgba(140, 140, 140)"
 let velocity = 0.05
 let amplitude = 100
 let delay = 0
 

 for( let i =0; i < 10; i++ ) {  
   circleArr.push(new Circle(x, y, radius, color, velocity, 
     amplitude, delay))
   x += radius * 2
   delay += 100
  // velocity += 0.001
  }
}


function animate(){
  // ellapsed time from the start (you should initialize start
  // closer to the animation start if there is a noticeably long
  // operation in between)
  const ellapsed = Date.now() - start;
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

  for(let i = 0; i < circleArr.length; i++) {
    // ellapsed is passed to the ball's update method
    circleArr[i].update(ellapsed)   
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}


init()
animate()
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas />
  </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you could initialize a start variable for each ball at the time we first call update on them (so that not all balls rely on a global start wich may not be meaningful for them)

**edit**:
After re reading your question I've noticed that you may look for another solution not involving delay. It's actually easier: just give each ball a different (incremented) starting radian.

Below I've replaced the additional delay parameter by a radian parameter:

```
    function Circle(x, y, radius, color, velocity, amplitude, radian) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.color = color
        this.radius = radius
        this.velocity = velocity
        this.amplitude = amplitude
        this.acceleration = 0.001
        this.count = 0
        this.radian = radian

        this.draw = function(){
            c.beginPath()
            c.fillStyle = color
            c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
            c.lineWidth = 3
            c.stroke()
            c.fill()
            c.closePath()
        }

        this.update = function(){

            this.draw()

            this.radian += this.velocity
            this.y = y + Math.sin(this.radian) * this.amplitude
            this.count ++


        }
    }
```

Then instead of feeding ellapsed time to each ball I've initialized them with an incremented radian:

```
    function init(){
        circleArr = []
        let radius = 25
        let x = radius
        let radian = 0
        let y = 130
        let color = "rgba(140, 140, 140)"
        let velocity = 0.05
        let amplitude = 100
        let delay = 0

        for( let i =0; i < 10; i++ ) {  
            circleArr.push(
                new Circle(
                    x, y,
                    radius, color,
                    velocity, amplitude, radian
                )
            )
            x += radius * 2
            radian += Math.PI / 10

            // velocity += 0.001
        }
    }
```

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight

function Circle(x, y, radius, color, velocity, amplitude, startRadian) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.color = color
  this.radius = radius
  this.velocity = velocity
  this.amplitude = amplitude
  this.acceleration = 0.001
  this.count = 0
  this.radian = startRadian


  this.draw = function(){
    c.beginPath()
    c.fillStyle = color
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
    c.lineWidth = 3
    c.stroke()
    c.fill()
    c.closePath()
 }

 this.update = function(){
   
   this.draw()
   this.radian += this.velocity
   this.y = y + Math.sin(this.radian) * this.amplitude
   this.count ++
   
   
  }
}



let circleArr;
function init(){
 circleArr = []
 let radius = 25
 let x = radius
 let radian = 0
 let y = 130
 let color = "rgba(140, 140, 140)"
 let velocity = 0.05
 let amplitude = 100
 let delay = 0

 for( let i =0; i < 10; i++ ) {  
   circleArr.push(new Circle(x, y, radius, color, velocity, 
     amplitude, radian))
   x += radius * 2
   radian += Math.PI / 10
  // velocity += 0.001
  }
}


function animate(){
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

  for(let i = 0; i < circleArr.length; i++) {
    circleArr[i].update()   
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}


init()
animate()
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas/>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works even better but will change the starting position of the balls.
You can achieve pretty cool effect by combinating the two techniques (radian offset + delay).

I let you experiment with the different parameters.

Comment: ha! this fixed it. it works exactly as I hoped it to!  thanks a lot :)